# allow users to post url schems that not http/https?

Tags: url, security, privacy

i have a blog comment section where users write their website and a comment about it and it is shown like this

```html
<a href="https://example.com">Website</a>
<br>
<span>my website is about...</span>
<br><br>
<a href="https://example2.com">Website2</a>
<br>
<span>my website2 is about...</span>
```

and i allow http/https url schemes only

some of my users told me they want to write a website or a connection using url schemes like `ftp:// - mailto: - file: - info:` to use them as

```html
<a href="ftp://example.com">Website</a>
<br>
<span>my website is about transfering to you</span>
<br><br>
<a href="file:example2.com/file.xml">Website2</a>
<br>
<span>my website2 is about sharing a file link to download</span>
<br><br>
<a href="mailto:name@example3.com">Website2</a>
<br>
<span>my website3 is to send me email for medical conditions</span>
```

is it safe for the viewer to allow this or it maybe dangers their privacy and security by suprise?

Comment: What will you do to guarantee that the links to files/ftp aren't malware?

Comment: @Trebor i thought of that but can malware be executed from these links unless opened?

Comment: If a user clicks on a link to a MS Word or Excel file that contains malware, most client computers will automatically open the file, triggering the malware.

Comment: @Trebor that mean all website giving MSWord Excelt download are also dangerious ?

Comment: They're all at risk.  Even Intel, the chip manufacturer, had a file years ago that contained a virus that spread when users opened the file.  It wasn't on purpose, but somehow got into production.  I will always scan docs for viruses/malware prior to opening if they don't come from a super reliable source.